# Spring Boot CRUD findall without orderBy: is the order predictable?

Tags: spring-boot

Does the list returned by a CRUD repository method such as the following have a predictable order?

`List<UserProfile> findAllByGroupKey (String groupKey);`

The database is MySQL 5 and Spring Boot version is 2.2.7. I'd like the order of the items in the list to be the same as they were stored in the database, but I'm not sure if it's enough to omit `orderBy' to achieve this result. I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: In sql without an imposed ordering you may get whatever order is convenient for the database. That will reflect how the rows happen to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing with the specified configuration (MySQL 5 and Spring Boot 2.2.7). The answer is definitely "no", at least if the index is not a progressive number (in my case it is an UUID).

The order is in no way predictable based on how the data was entered.

The only way to get the rows in the same order as they were entered into the database is to add an additional sort variable (such as a sequence number or a timestamp) and explicitly sort the rows with "orderBy" based on that variable.